# Как реализовать поиск по txt файлу?

Tags: поиск, php

Как реализовать поиск по txt файлу?

Comment: а можно добавить конкретики? что исчем, какого размера файл ожидаем на входе?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
function str_search($path, $extension, $str)
{
        $file_arr = array();
        foreach (glob(rtrim($path, '/')."/*.".$extension) as $filename)
        {
                if(strstr(file_get_contents($filename), $str) != false)
                $file_arr[] = $filename;
        }
        return $file_arr;
}

str_search('my_dir', 'файл.txt', 'строка поиска');
```

Comment: все ра6отает, спс=0

Answer (score 10):

```
if (strpos(file_get_contents("filename.txt"), "Искомая строка"))
echo "Искомая строка найдена";  
else echo "Искомая строка отсутствует";
```

Comment: Если что-нибудь не понятно, спрашивайте.

Comment: интересно а если файлик весом в 500 метров будет - ваш скрипт нормально отработает?

Comment: Повсеместно пятисотмегабайтные файлы txt встречаются, вы правы. Но, всё-таки, думаю, что мой скрипт вполне удовлетворит автора вопроса. А если всё-таки будет необходим поиск по файлам большого размера, он укажет это в вопросе.

Comment: а можно сделать чтобы искало не только строки а слова или буквы ? и ещё вопрос: как сделать чтобы \n обозначало что это конец строки?

Comment: Вместо "Искомая строка", внутри кавычек можно ввести хоть слово, хоть букву, хоть предложение. 
Не понял вопроса про перенос строки. Уточните, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

протестировал разные функции на файле с 1 млн записей результат следующий

```
 if(!strpos(file_get_contents('file.txt'), $ip)){ // время выполнения 0,39 сек
 if (isset(explode(file_get_contents('file.txt'), $ip)))[1])) { //время выполнения 0,53 сек
 if (preg_grep("/^" . $ip . "/i", file('file.txt'))) { //время выполнения  1,01 сек
```

Может кто знает более быстрые способы ?