# Найти определенное слово из файла (PHP)

Tags: php

Нужно отобразить файлы из директории содержащие определенное слово. Нахожу файлы из директории:

```
$filename = "/";
foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename) {
 echo "{$filename}<br/>";
}
```

как сделать, чтобы отображались только файлы с искомым словом?

Comment: 1. Читаете файл, 2. Ищите в нем слово, 3. Если слово найдено - выводите имя файла. С каким именно этапом возникают проблемы? Где ваша попытка решения?

Comment: Возможно вы написали дублирующийся вопрос: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/137985/Как-реализовать-поиск-по-txt-файлу     

Уточните, что именно вы подразумеваете под "найти определенное слово"? Нужно найти именно слово, или просто подстроку? Решения задач будут разные.

Answer (score 1):

```
$phrase='blablabla';

foreach (glob("*.php") as $filename) {
  if(strpos(file_get_contents($filename),$phrase) !== false)  echo "{$filename}<br/>";
}
```